# Makefile:72: *** multiple target patterns. Stop. while trying to install imapsync on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

i'm getting an error as "Makefile:72: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop." while trying to install imapsync on my ubuntu server 14.04

Comment: Can you provide the sample of your Makefile? Have you checked other SO questions with the similar errors?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem hence didn't find a proper solution but yes ofcourse a approx answer

git clone https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync.git
and after downloading it just go inside the imapsync directory

Error comes here which you showed above when you run make install so for alternate i use ./imapsync but it show error also and asked for install two more modules and after that i can use imapsync command here only in this directory but it saves my life

these are the two extra modules

sudo cpanm Sys::MemInfo

sudo cpanm Regexp::Common module

Answer (score 0):

In the Makefile, change ::= to := to be compatible with older make than 2012.

https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync/issues/162#issuecomment-474866494